# Reading binary file bitwise in R

Tags: r, byte, decode, bit, binary-data

Since I am not a programmer I got stuck solving this probably trivial problem: I would like to extract numeric values from binary file ([example.Lis](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/84ej3vwl5ijrefu/AAAdcGxrpZrFayY3JvHed-aLa?dl=0)) using R. First 256 bytes contain a header. I know the header structure therefore I was able to decode its content. For instance, according the [format description](http://www.ortec-online.com/download/List-Mode-File-Formats.pdf), OLE DATE information is stored in bytes 8-15 as a double data type. To read this, I simply used following command:

```
my.file = file("example.Lis", "rb")
headall<-readBin(my.file, raw(), n=256, size=1)
readBin(headall[9:16],double(),size=8,n=1)

[1] 42438.66
```

Header is followed by a series of 32-bit data records. Each record contain multiple integer values, so it is not possible to proceed byte-wise as in the header case. Is it somehow possible to read the file bit-wise to decode the numbers inside each record?

As the [format description states](http://www.ortec-online.com/download/List-Mode-File-Formats.pdf) (page 4), 32-bit words are encoded as follows:

[image: Format description- bit-wise]

Comment: You get the binary representation by using `rawToBits(headall)`.